# Pre-render Error on Vercel. Nextjs 13.4.0

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, prerender, headless-ui

My website works fine on Nextjs 13.3.4 but when I update it to Nextjs 13.4.0 I'm getting a pre-render issue. I tried finding a particular page that is causing the issue but literally all the page failing to get pre-rendered. This issue is only happening on the vercel console. When I run "yarn run build" locally, the output is fine.
[image: sample error - same error repeated for over 400 pages]

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/careers/content-specialist". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at exports.useRef (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
    at y (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/hooks/use-sync-refs.js:1:178)
    at Ke (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/components/listbox/listbox.js:1:4762)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:118:245)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
    at He (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:123:155)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:115:215)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:115:9)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at exports.useRef (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
    at y (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/hooks/use-sync-refs.js:1:178)
    at Ke (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/components/listbox/listbox.js:1:4762)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:118:245)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
    at He (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:123:155)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:115:215)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
    at Ge (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:115:9)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:120:91)
```

Updated **nextjs 13.3.4** to **nextjs 13.4.0**  Tried removing all headless UI stuff, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Next.js Version 13.4.2+ and above, the issue will not occur.